# Parse JSON response with quotes - Twitter error handling

Tags: javascript, json

Am getting a twitter error response like the following json as my response body. I would like to check a condition if there is any error occurs. 
**Twitter response**

{"errors":[{"code":186,"message":"Status is over 140 characters."}]}

But here the twitter response errors is in quotes. So i cannot access it. Could you please help me to solve this issue. Thank you

my code

```
tuwm.post(content, media_picture.picture, function(response) {
                    if(response.body.errors) {
                        console.log('error')

                    } else {
                    res.json({
                        status: 200,
                        info: "OK",
                        id: response.id
                    });
                    }       
                });
```

Comment: in quotes. A string?*

Comment: `JSON.parse(response)` ?